# Current electricity formula

Tags: electricity, electric-current

In the given formula 
\begin{equation}
I = enAv_d
\end{equation}
does the value of n remain constant or change with the change in shape of the conductor?

Comment: I thin d should be a subscript for current, it is only for charge that it enters the formula http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Comment: @annav it's the drift velocity of the electron.

Comment: Pay close attention to what happens if you divide both sides by A. $\frac{I}{A}=J=(ne)(v_d)=\rho v_d$ J is a special quantity called Current Density, $\rho$  is charge density. They have an important relationship regarding conservation of charge.

Answer (score 1):

n is the number of free electrons per $\mathrm{m}^{-3}$ in any wire or conductor, imagine a block of mass with density $ρ$ $\mathrm {kg\,m}^{-3} $ , now if we were to take a small piece of it from the block,density of the smaller chunk will still be $ρ$ $\mathrm {kg\,m}^{-3} $ .Thus there will be no change in $n$ when its shape is changed.

Comment: note that there should not be a d dependence of current  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Comment: @annav yeah,he didn't use mathjax I guess

Comment: it's the drift velocity @PiGuy

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is the number of charge carriers per unit volume and it does not depend on the shape of the conductor.